# nginx proxy_pass and docker - I don't want port number in address bar

Tags: nginx, wordpress, docker, proxypass

On mywebsite.com, I have running docker container with wordpress.
I started it as

```
docker run -p 8000:80 --name docker-wordpress-nginx -d
```

and

```
docker ps
```

shows

```
0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

and on my host I have nginx running with

```
server {
     listen   80;
...
server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
...
location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

when i go here

```
mywebsite.com
```

It brings wordpress index page of my site, but address in browser is now

```
mywebsite.com:8000
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.com
```

which I expected.
Everything looks as i wanted except that I always get that port number in address

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/2015/08/01/hello-world/
```

Instead, I wanted

```
http://mywebsite.com/2015/08/01/hello-world/
```

i mean, in general, instead of

```
http://mywebsite.com:8000/some_blog/
```

i want

```
http://mywebsite.com/some_blog/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your Wordpress site URL into yours. Read [Changing the Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

One of solutions is modified your `wp-config.php` file. Add/replace the following configuration:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.com');
```

If you don't have any other site in port 80, you can simply expose your port 80 into Wordpress port.

Comment: Great! It works exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot Edward!

Comment: You're welcome @DarkoStefanovic. Are you new here? If you feel this answer is good and solve your problem, please accept the answer by click the check mark beside the answer :)

Comment: Hello, I am new. And i will do that now. I have another-additional related question though, when i go to mywebsite.com/wp-admin it redirects to /wp-login.php and displays "File not found". So, it seems that i need to set those variables somewhere else, or some other variables. Should I post another/different question about this?

Comment: Are your /wp-login.php exist?

Comment: Yup, you can create a new one. I thought it is a new problem and might be not so related with your main question here.